# What is the meaning of "Acting Coordinator"?

Tags: meaning

He is holding the job position of "Acting Coordinator" of xxx team.
What is "Acting Coordinator"?

Comment: An 'acting' role is one that someone holds temporarily while the post is vacant and awaiting a new official appointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the team's co-ordinator  is having a prolonged absence. Somebody has taken on the duties of of the coordinator, but hasn't actually been officially appointed as coordinator.